# Migrating users' alerts from SharePoint on-premises 2013 to SharePoint Online. is this a supported operation

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, administration, alert, office

I am planning to migrate our On-Premises SharePoint 2013 enterprise farm to office 365 (SharePoint online).

For migrating the sites, I am planning to do the following main tasks:-

1. Develop and deploy my server side event receiver to work as remote event receivers.
2. Using third party tool, I am going to migrate the site settings and data.

but the third party tool mentioned that every thing can be migrated from on-premises to office 365, except for the user alerts. where these users' alerts can not be migrated.

so my question is, if there is a way to migrate the users' alerts from on-premises to office 365? or this operation is not supported inside SharePoint ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To migrate the user alerts, you can use Metalogix to copy site and list level alerts from one SharePoint environment to SharePoint Online targets.

More information, you can refer to:

https://www.metalogix.com/help/Content%20Matrix%20Console/SharePoint%20Edition/002_HowTo/003_MigrationActions/021_CopyAlerts.htm

For professional information about the third-party tool, you can ask the third party support for help.

https://www.metalogix.com/

Comment: the first link is no longer available